# websphere url context error (JSPG0036E)

Tags: websphere-6.1, j-security-check

Issue on Websphere 6.1 I hope I'm missing something obvious: We have an application which gets deployed to a configured Websphere environment. We're trying to mimic this WebSphere configuration on a different platform (Linux vs Solaris), but maybe we're missing some obvious settings. The application deploys and starts without an error, but after logon on url `localhost:port/app/index.jsp`
(via j_spring_security_check) Websphere redirects to `localhost:port/index.jsp`. This gives an JSP processing Error (HTTPError 404), with code JSPG0036E.

The webapplication is wrapped in an ear, because those are the standards here. And that ear works well on our solaris WAS 6.1 environment but not on the linux WAS. Furthermore in development we've the wrapped war running on Tomcat without problem.

I think I missed the context root somewhere but It's not to be found in Websphere's console, I wouldn't be surprised if it is a Websphere (6.1.0.33) Bug, hopefully I'm wrong or are there workarounds?

Comment: If the context root were wrong, I'd expect your /app/index.jsp to fail. But you can check it in the console at Enterprise Applications > Application > Context Root For Web Modules.

Comment: thanks for your reaction. context root is there it does display a space in front of the appname though which is not present in the context root set in the ear.